# Event listener won't call Class

Tags: javascript, function, class, this

The inputBtn is the button that submits the form values to wherever but I set to preventDefault so that the logic can use the data from it. The console logs work and shows the product name and price but for some reason won't call addInventory function. The addInventory function works outside of the event listener but returns/does nothing when inside it. I'm thinking it might be a THIS issue but I'm out of brain power and need another opinion on it.

Thanks in advance.

```
class Album {
    constructor(title, artist, price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.price = price;
    }
}

const addInventory = (title, artist, price) => {
    const newAdd = new Album (title, artist, price);
    products.push(newAdd);
    // products.push()
};

const testPush = function(item) {
    products.push(item);
}
addInventory(`Internet`, `Donald Glover`, 15);
addInventory(`Black Pumas`, `Black Pumas`, 31);
// testPush(23);

    const productName = document.getElementById(`product-name`);
    console.log(productName);
    const productPrice = document.getElementById(`product-price`);
    console.log(productPrice);
    const inputBtn = document.getElementById(`inputBtn`);
    console.log(inputBtn);
    
    inputBtn.addEventListener(`click`, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(productName.value, ` `, +productPrice.value);
        addInventory(productName.value, ` `, +productPrice.value);
    })
     
console.log(products);

// Product list mutation needs to happen before the loop function 
// so that data will be the most updated version everytime

// A div box will be created for every element in the product array
for (const everyElement of products) {
    gridChild();
    console.log(everyElement);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="app">
</div>
<div class = "inventory-gui">
    
        <input type="text" id="product-name" name="product-name" data-product="info"><br>     
        <input type="number" id="product-price" name="product-price" data-product="info"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" id="inputBtn">Make a new item</button>
      
</div>
```

Javascript that renders html

```
"use strict";



// DIV NESTING USING ONLY JS
const app = document.querySelector(`.app`);


const div = `<div class="grid-child">
            </div>`;

const gridContainer = `<div class="grid-container"></div>`;

// New products will be pushed in here
const products = [];


const gridParent = function() {
    // app.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, gridContainer);
    app.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, gridContainer);
}

gridParent();
const gridContainerDiv = document.querySelector(`.grid-container`);

const gridChild = function() {
    gridContainerDiv.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, div);
}
```

Comment: your code work, please post your html snippet

Comment: Just did. Im really leaning into thinking it might be a this issue from the event listener but i'm not too sure on the syntax.

Comment: `addInventory` is work just call console.log inside the function, it append an object to the `products` or what else should `addInventory` do?

Comment: addInventory is supposed to create a new object that is pushed to the products array. A for of loop goes through the products array and creates a div block for every product in the array.

Answer (score 0):

`gridChild()` is static, it append empty div, you have to make the function accept parameter like `gridChild(obj)` and call it every time new inventory added.

```js
// DIV NESTING USING ONLY JS
const app = document.querySelector(`.app`);

const gridContainer = `<div class="grid-container"></div>`;

// New products will be pushed in here
const products = [];


const gridParent = function() {
  // app.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, gridContainer);
  app.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, gridContainer);
}

gridParent();

const gridContainerDiv = document.querySelector(`.grid-container`);

const gridChild = function(product) { // <= accept parameter
 let div = `<div class="grid-child">
    ${product.title}, ${product.artist}, ${product.price}
    </div>`;
  gridContainerDiv.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, div);
}

class Album {
  constructor(title, artist, price) {
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.price = price;
  }
}

const addInventory = (title, artist, price) => {
  const newAdd = new Album(title, artist, price);
  products.push(newAdd);
  gridChild(newAdd); // <== create and apppend the element
};

const testPush = function(item) {
  products.push(item);
}
addInventory(`Internet`, `Donald Glover`, 15);
addInventory(`Black Pumas`, `Black Pumas`, 31);
// testPush(23);

const productName = document.getElementById(`product-name`);
//console.log(productName);
const productPrice = document.getElementById(`product-price`);
//console.log(productPrice);
const inputBtn = document.getElementById(`inputBtn`);
//console.log(inputBtn);

inputBtn.addEventListener(`click`, function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(productName.value, ` `, +productPrice.value);
  addInventory(productName.value, ` `, +productPrice.value);
})

// loop not needed, removed
```

```html
<div class="app">
</div>
<div class="inventory-gui">
  <input type="text" id="product-name" name="product-name" data-product="info"><br>
  <input type="number" id="product-price" name="product-price" data-product="info"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" id="inputBtn">Make a new item</button>

</div>
```